# Include all chracters in Linux find command

Tags: linux, bash

To `-name`parameter of `find` command, when I give `*-release` it shows the files, but when I try `*release`, command ignores the files which contains `-` or the other special characters.

```
test@host:~$ find /etc -name *-release 2>/dev/null
/etc/lsb-release
/etc/update-manager/meta-release
/etc/os-release

test@host:~$ find /etc -name *release 2>/dev/null
test@host:~$
```

I want to get all files even if they contains special characters or not.

Comment: Have you tried single-quoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out, using single-quoting works as I expected.

Instead of `*release`, `'*release'` must be used.

Thanks for Enrico.